# What are ways to change log level at runtime depending on occurrence rate

Tags: java, logging, sentry

I would like to know whether there are conventional ways (probably some third-party libraries) to help me with the following problem. I would like to have an ability to change log level depending on occurrence rate. For example, if I catch some exception and it happens say once an hour I would like to log it with the WARN level. But if the rate becomes higher then I would like to switch to the ERROR level. The purpose of this behavior is to not get distracted by rare sporadic exceptions that are inevitable in general but shouldn't be brought to developers' attention unless there is a sufficient amount of them. When I open Sentry summary page I would like to see only what's really important and requires attention, not some rare request failures that will inevitably happen from time to time. But at the same time I can't just use WARN level because if there are many such failures then there's clearly something bad going on and it requires attention.

To better illustrate what I mean here's how in my opinion that could be done with an imaginary third-party library that would imitate (or be a wrapper over) slf4j/commons-logging:

```
LOG.warn("Failed to send request to ...", e).onRate(Rates.hourlyMoreThan(5)).switchTo(LogLevel.ERROR);
```

An alternative would be an option in Sentry not to show events (matching some criteria like a class of the exception) with a low occurrence rate but as far as I know that's not possible.

Comment: What logging library?

Comment: Well, I use Logback + slf4j as a wrapper, but it's not that important, I would like to know whether it's possible for any logging library at all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do this with Log4j (other logging frameworks should have similar structures), this can probably be done with a custom appender. If that appender sees one message too many times, it could try to change the category's (or the logger's) level.

Here is how you could create your own Appender:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html

Here is what the appender would have to do to reconfigure the logging:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html

Comment: Looks promising, thanks, will take a look and come back

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is possible to filter in Sentry UI, but you an definitely create a custom Sentry appender based on [SentryAppender](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/main/sentry-logback/src/main/java/io/sentry/logback/SentryAppender.java) which will measure the occurrence and emit event to Sentry only when it reaches certain threshold.